# Can we increase the reputation per answer uptick to 20?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Many economists, contemporary or otherwise, argue that controlled measured inflation is good for an economy as it can be shown to increase productivity.

With the recent doubling of question reputation to 10 points per uptick, how about doubling the answer reputation to 20?

Furthermore, we could make question and answer downvotes -4 (the cost to the voter for the latter becomes -2), and good pre-4k reputation edits +4.

In order to maintain a sense of motivation, perhaps we could double all the privilege thresholds, including the SWAG which would now be at 200k and 500k?

What do you all think?

Comment: If we increase votes to be 50 EXP each that will make it a more welcoming community of ad revenue

Comment: How about 100?  Anyone for 200?

Comment: Your question would be a better one if you provided some rationale.  Otherwise, this just looks like a troll question, and I think we've all had enough of that nonsense.

Comment: @RobertHarvey "as it can be shown to increase productivity"

Comment: I said "rationale," not "hand-waving."

Comment: Why should this require any additional rationale than the other?

Comment: Rather we should increase the downvote weight from 2 to 5 or 8.

Comment: What's the point of increasing every single value? This isn't an economy, and you don't sell things to others for reputation, and you don't buy things from others for reputation.

Comment: @KevinB: The rationale for the 5 to 10 reputation increase is that the original decrease to 5 rep did nothing to increase question quality, which is true.  Whether that's a reasonable argument or not I leave as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: @MerajalMaksud: Yes, personally I believe it should be symmetrical - else you have the absurd consequence that a question like this is net reputation gaining.

Comment: No evidence of that was provided.

Comment: @KevinB: It's the New SE Corporate™.  You were expecting double-blind, peer-reviewed studies?

Comment: Only if we also upgrade the *question* rep to 20...

Comment: Anyone whom can **answer questions** on: [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Unanswered), [Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions?tab=Unanswered), [Operations Research](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Unanswered), [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Unanswered), [Quantum Computing](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Unanswered), etc. is more than welcome to do so, ***or*** oppose an increase to the value of the Q&As - they can take a long time to write, and require considerable expertise.

Comment: I wanna be Jon Skeet! Make it a million!

Answer (score 3):

> Many economists, contemporary or otherwise, argue that controlled measured inflation is good for an economy as it can be shown to increase productivity.

1. Economists are infamous for ideological biases and failure to predict fateful events (like the 2008 financial collapse).
2. "Productivity" is a problematic concept. By common metrics, if you produce and sell a popular but low-quality product that breaks down quickly and has to be re-purchased, you're super productive, but if you make a few exquisite articles that are a marvel to behold and inspire artists and scientists, but don't sell them - then you're a bum who produces nothing.
3. We're talking about website gamification here. It's not an economy.

> With the recent doubling of question reputation to 10 points per uptick, how about doubling the answer reputation to 20?

Honestly - you're giving me a headache :-(

> Furthermore, we could make question and answer downvotes -4 (the cost to the voter for the latter becomes -2), and good pre-4k reputation edits +4.

Ow, my head!

... seriously, though, one (undiscussed) change at a time. Let's let the dust settle on the latest change.

> In order to maintain a sense of motivation, perhaps we could double all the privilege thresholds,

You say 'we' - but 'we' have no control over any of that stuff these days; SE Inc. doesn't engage with us and decides unilaterally. Also, you're making several unfounded assumptions, such as lack of motivation, or no need for people with those privileges etc.

> including the SWAG which would now be at 200k and 500k?

Do they even give out swag these days?

Comment: Apologies for causing you a headache. Ouch! Have an upvote; I hope that helps a little: It’s all I can do really.